# Disable auto clean in apt

Tags: debian, apt

I don't want to clean `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, I need to stay my deb files there. Which apt option can works for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the `Keep-Downloaded-Packages` for `apt`:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "1";
```

in `apt.conf` or an `/etc/apt.conf.d/` snippet, *e.g.*

```
echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "1";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10apt-keep-downloads
```

(`apt` doesn’t really “auto clean”, it doesn’t keep downloaded packages.)